# Stuck converting decimal with decimal values

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert decimal and its converting but I want my output with decimal values for example.

If I convert 1 then I am expecting 1.00

Here is my code

```
decimal AL;

switch (CurrentScore)
{ 
    case 1:
        AL = Convert.ToDecimal(1.00);
       break;
    case 2:
        AL =  Convert.ToDecimal(1.5);
        break;
    case 3:
        AL = Convert.ToDecimal(2.00);
        break;
    default:
        AL = Convert.ToDecimal(0.00);
        break;
}

return AL;
```

but this always return like integer.

For example if my currentscore is "1" then I am expecting to return AL = 1.00 but it always returns "1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decimals (and other numeric types) don't have formatting embedded. `1 == 1.0 == 1.00`.

If you want to *display* them formatted with 2 decimal places, then do something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(AL.ToString("0.00"));
```

Also note that you don't have to use `Convert.ToDecimal` here. You can just say `AL = 1.00`.